# Biblatex: How to add comment to autocite?

Tags: biblatex, citing

I am trying to add some text to a citation that is put as a footer.
The citation references to an earlier citation but has a different page. So far it works like this:

```
While Adams himself does not think that his premise (4) 
is very debatable\autocite[347-348]{RobertAdams1991}, blabla
```

[image]

Now I want to add some text after the "348."

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Does `\autocite[\ppno~347--348, see also his earlier work]{RobertAdams1991}` do what you want? You will have to use `\ppno` or `\pno` (the former is for pages, the latter for one page) to force the page prefix before the page numbers; you do not have to do this if the argument only contains numbers (and a few other characters such as `347-348` or `347--348`).

Comment: An alternative would be `\autocites(see also his earlier work)[347-348]{RobertAdams1991}`: multicite commands allow a different notation for "global" pre and post-notes (i.e., notes printed before and after the whole citation command), via `\autocites(<multiprenote>)(<multipostnote>)[<prenote 1>][<postnote 1>]{<entry 1>}[<prenote n>][<postnote n>]{<entry n>}`. See § 3.7.3 of the [documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/biblatex)

Comment: thanks both solution work ! I prefer the latter though :)

Comment: @henrique You should turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Using the same citation mecanism you're already working with, you can add any kind of information to the `postnote` argument: Just keep in mind that if the contents of this argument is not numerical, `biblatex` will not be able to automatically format it: `biblatex` can turn `[347-348]` into `pp.~347-348` (or `[347--348]` into `pp.~347--348`), but it does not know what is a page range and what is a textual note in `[347-348, see also his earlier work]`. In other words, it can parse number ranges as page ranges, but anything else will disturb this automation and be treated as a textual string. So you should use `\autocite[\ppno~347--348, see his earlier work]{RobertAdams1991}` as suggested by moewe. See §3.7.1 (as well as §3.7.8, on `\pno`, `\ppno` and other commands related to page ranges notation) of the [documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/biblatex).
2. An alternative would be to use the multicite mechanism:`\autocites(see also his earlier work)[347-348]{RobertAdams1991}`. Multicite commands allow a different notation for “global” pre and post-notes (i.e., notes printed before and after the whole citation command), via `\autocites(<multiprenote>)(<multipostnote>)[<prenote 1>][<postnote 1>]{<entry 1>}[<prenote n>][<postnote n>]{<entry n>}` Just like with regular citation commands, when there's only one of the arguments it treats it as the post-note. See § 3.7.3 of the [documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/biblatex).

Here's a MWE exploring these possibilities:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\autocite[347--348]{knuth:ct} is the same as
\autocite[\ppno~347--348]{knuth:ct}

\autocite[347--348, see also his earlier work]{knuth:ct} is
\emph{not} the same as \autocite[\ppno~347--348, see also his earlier
work]{knuth:ct}

Another option is to use the multicite mechanism: \autocites(see also
his earlier work)[347--348]{knuth:ct} (which is the same as
\autocites()(see also his earlier work)[][347--348]{knuth:ct} 

\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]